# import netbeans generated Cobertura report xml into Sonar

Tags: ant, junit, code-coverage, sonarqube, cobertura

I have generated my cobertura code covergage report using ant from netbeans but not able to import cobertura generated xml report into sonar.

My plugin version using is as below : 
sonar-java-plugin-2.2
sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.6
Sonarqube version 4.3

Also code coberage generated junit xml report is generated with name "TEST-" followed by class name with full package due to which resource found error showing while analyzing project in sonar using sonar-runner due to which 0-test file analyzed showed while analysis but that i resolved by removing prefix "TEST" from java file.

Please Help to import sonarqube generated xml report into sonar.

Answer (score 0):

The version 1.6 of cobertura plugin contains a bug that prevent import of reports. The 1.6.1 version fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer.

can you please provide link where I can download cobertura plugin version 1.6.1.

Comment: Here is the link to the SonarQube Cobertura plugin http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Cobertura+Plugin